# "No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR" after accidentally deleting EFI partition

Tags: linux, boot

I used to dual-boot windows and debian linux and then decided to delete windows. During the process I accidentally also deleted the EFI partition, which I managed to fix but now every time I boot into linux the following message stays on screen for 10 seconds before proceeding to boot: (copied from `journalctl -b`)

```
DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x00000000c9000000-0x00000000cb7fffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x00000000c9000000-0x00000000cb7fffff]
BIOS vendor: FUJITSU // Insyde Software Corp.; Ver: Version 1.22; Product Version: 10601736746
```

After some googling I think the error is both unfixable and unimportant, but if so I would appreciate a way to hide it.

More system information:

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64
Host: LIFEBOOK E756 10601736746 
Kernel: 5.10.0-13-amd64
```

EDIT: Upon looking at the output of `dmesg` for memory regions overlapping with the one in the error message, I found this:

```
[    0.022014] Reserving Intel graphics memory at [mem 0xc9800000-0xcb7fffff]
```

EDIT2: [Here's the `dmesg` logs.](https://pastebin.com/Xcg4SmWP)

Comment: You could try a BIOS update to the latest version (even to the same version as installed) and `fsck` of the disk.

Comment: Does your kernel command line have the `add_efi_memmap` option? Try either adding or removing it.

Comment: @user1686 It does not, I tried adding it and nothing changed.

Comment: @harrymc `fsck` returns all clean. I'll wait to see if any other suggestions appear before trying to update my BIOS since messing it up would be very bad...

Answer (score 3):

Using a HP Z4 G4 running AlmaLinux 8.7 with a `4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64` Kernel had seen these errors in dmesg:

```
[    0.001029] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x0000006c30a000 end: 0x0000006c30cfff
[    0.001030] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000006c30a000-0x000000006c30cfff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[    0.001035] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x000000006c30a000-0x000000006c30cfff]
               BIOS vendor: HP; Ver: P61 v02.86; Product Version:
```

The BIOS version is the latest from HP, and is less than one month old. I.e. in this case there is no BIOS update to try.

On investigation found the reporting of the Firmware Bug is causing the Kernel to be tainted:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted 
2048
$  ~/Downloads/kernel-chktaint 
Kernel is "tainted" for the following reasons:
 * workaround for bug in platform firmware applied (#11)
For a more detailed explanation of the various taint flags see
 Documentation/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.rst in the Linux kernel sources
 or https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/tainted-kernels.html
Raw taint value as int/string: 2048/'G
```

The Firmware Bug is reported from the following in the `arch/x86/include/asm/iommu.h` source file in the Kernel:

```c
static inline int __init
arch_rmrr_sanity_check(struct acpi_dmar_reserved_memory *rmrr)
{
    u64 start = rmrr->base_address;
    u64 end = rmrr->end_address + 1;

    if (e820__mapped_all(start, end, E820_TYPE_RESERVED))
        return 0;

    pr_err(FW_BUG "No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [%#018Lx-%#018Lx], contact BIOS vendor for fixes\n",
           start, end - 1);
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

The `dmar_parse_one_rmrr` function in `drivers/iommu/intel/iommu.c` calls `arch_rmrr_sanity_check`:

```c
    if (rmrr_sanity_check(rmrr)) {
        pr_warn(FW_BUG
               "Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [%#018Lx-%#018Lx]\n"
               "BIOS vendor: %s; Ver: %s; Product Version: %s\n",
               rmrr->base_address, rmrr->end_address,
               dmi_get_system_info(DMI_BIOS_VENDOR),
               dmi_get_system_info(DMI_BIOS_VERSION),
               dmi_get_system_info(DMI_PRODUCT_VERSION));
        add_taint(TAINT_FIRMWARE_WORKAROUND, LOCKDEP_STILL_OK);
    }
```

I.e. the `arch_rmrr_sanity_check` failing explains both the `No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR` and `Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR` messages and the Kernel being tainted.

dmesg shows the following for the BIOS-provided physical RAM map:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000087fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000088000-0x0000000000088fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000089000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000006bc6ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006bc70000-0x000000006c143fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006c144000-0x000000006cb76fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006cb77000-0x000000006cc52fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006cc53000-0x000000006fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070000000-0x000000008fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe010000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000047fffffff] usable
```

Where the `ACPI NVS` region in the BIOS memory map overlaps the RMRR.

As noted above the `arch_rmrr_sanity_check` function in the `4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64` Kernel causes a Firmware Bug to be reported if the memory region of the RMRR isn't marked as reserved by the BIOS-provided physical RAM map. Found the [iommu/vt-d: Allow NVS regions in arch_rmrr_sanity_check()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5566e68d829f5d87670d5984c1c2ccb4c518405f) commit which modifies the arch_rmrr_sanity_check function to allow the RMRR region to be marked as either *reserved* or *ACPI NVS* in the BIOS-provided physical RAM map. Haven't yet checked which is the first mainline Kernel version that commit appears in, nor if has already been backported by RHEL.

As a work-around booted with `memmap=10444K%0x6c144000-4+2` added to the command line. What this does is to change the type of the ACPI NVS region from `E820_TYPE_NVS` (4) to `E820_TYPE_RESERVED` (2) early in the boot, so by the time `arch_rmrr_sanity_check` is called the RMRR memory region is considered reserved and the sanity check passes.

The syntax of the `memmap` option used is from [kernel-parameters.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
    memmap=<size>%<offset>-<oldtype>+<newtype>
            [KNL,ACPI] Convert memory within the specified region
            from <oldtype> to <newtype>. If "-<oldtype>" is left
            out, the whole region will be marked as <newtype>,
            even if previously unavailable. If "+<newtype>" is left
            out, matching memory will be removed. Types are
            specified as e820 types, e.g., 1 = RAM, 2 = reserved,
            3 = ACPI, 12 = PRAM.
```

Where:

- `10444K` is the `<size>` taken from the `ACPI NVS` entry in the `BIOS-provided physical RAM map` output from dmesg
- `0x6c144000` is the start `<offset>`  taken from the `ACPI NVS` entry in the `BIOS-provided physical RAM map` output from dmesg
- `-4` is the `<oldtype>` which is the `E820_TYPE_NVS` macro in the Kernel source
- `+2` is the `<newtype>` which is the `E820_TYPE_RESERVED` macro in the Kernel source

As a result, the `No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR` and `Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR` messages are no longer reported and the Kernel was no longer tainted:

```
$ ~/Downloads/kernel-chktaint 
Kernel not Tainted
```

Initially tested the change temporarily by stopping at grub and editing the command line. When that worked, made the change permanent by using `grubby` to edit the command line:

```
$ sudo grubby --update-kernel=DEFAULT --args=memmap=10444K%0x6c144000-4+2
```

While the above addition of `memmap=10444K%0x6c144000` is specific to a particular model of PC / BIOS, hopefully it provides some guidance on how to suppress the Firmware Bug messages.

The above analysis also found a commit to the `arch_rmrr_sanity_check` function in the Kernel source code which should avoid the need for the work-around, without needing a BIOS change. Not sure when the Kernel change will make it into different distributions.

**Update**: Following an update to AlmaLinux 8.9 which uses a `4.18.0-513.5.1.el8_9.x86_64` Kernel then no longer needed to apply the `memmap` work-around. I.e. the later Kernel is no longer reporting a firmware bug when when the `RMRR` reported by the BIOS is within an `ACPI NVS` region. In [Kernel update has removed the Firmware Bug report](https://gist.github.com/Chester-Gillon/e5a1241a3f81b242e66b16078bc233aa#22-kernel-update-has-removed-the-firmware-bug-report) confirmed that the behaviour of the BIOS hasn't changed.

Comment: Very well written! But while trying to figure out which ACPI NVS entry corresponds to the memory region in question I found out none of them do. Looking further, I found the following line in `dmesg`:
`[    0.022014] Reserving Intel graphics memory at [mem 0xc9800000-0xcb7fffff]`. Will update the question with this info

Comment: @umnikos Can you show the dmesg output from ``BIOS-provided physical RAM map`` to the final following ``BIOS-e820`` entry? That can help to clarify the type of region.

Comment: Done, posted more than that in case you need it

Comment: @umnikos I can't see anything in the BIOS-e820 map which covers the problematic ``RMRR [0x00000000c9000000-0x00000000cb7fffff]`` range. If you try adding ``memmap=40M\$3216M`` to the command line that will mark the RMRR region as reserved and hopefully suppress the Firmware Bug. The ``\$`` is to escape the dollar for the grub bootloader.